# Bottom navigation from material-ui for React JS is not properly displayed in some screen sizes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Implemented bottom navigation bar from material ui in a react application. In few screens (eg., Iphone 5, Galaxy S5), the drawer is not completely displayed and the edges are chopped off, where else for other mobile browsers (eg. Pixel 2, etc), things are working fine. Is there any elegant fix for the same?  [In Iphone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9QKZ.png)   [In Pixel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTQGN.png)

Style being used with the component:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    boxShadow: '0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: '.53rem',
    fontWeight: 500,
    textDecoration: 'none',
  },
};
```

Comment: what are you using to test this? I just created a div with those same styles and nothing gets cut off for me...also what did you mean by drawer? are you using a drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Add React Material-UI CssBaseline component into your class. This helped me.